# How to get instance variable recognized as string? For an email?

Tags: python, string, email, smtplib

A class I created has a function `.email_template` that produces a string.

In my code, I have stored instance variables in a list, `inst`. As such, `inst[randint(1,100)].email_template()` produces a string.

I'm using smtplib in Python to send an email containing the string produced by `inst[randint(1,100)].email_template()`. However, this piece of code that determines the content of the email is tripping me up:

> `msg = str(inst[randint(1,100)].email_template())
>   server.sendmail(From, Recipient, msg)`

The `msg` argument in the second line has to be a string, which is why I used the `str()`method in a beginners attempt to make this go through. The email works, but the body simply says "None" when there should be a string appearing (and it does appear successfully on the console).

Going back to the title of this question, how can I get my instance variable code recognized as a string so that it successfully gets printed on an email?

Comment: Looks like you are printing the string in `email_template`, not returning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As thefourtheye put forward, my issue was printing the text in `email_template`, not returning it. Problem solved!